# Javascript "pre set" a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to declare a variable whose value is another variable that isn't set at that time.

```
var add = 1 + three;
var three = 3;
document.getElementById('thediv').innerHTML = add;
//results in "NaN"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seSMx/1/

Is there a way to do this using Jquery/Javascript?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why not `var three = 3; var add = 1 + three;`? >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/seSMx/2/ <<

Comment: If I told you, would you have an answer?

Comment: It may suggest an alternative solution if you explained what you're doing (and why).

Comment: @Dasarp You might want to put that as an answer, instead of a comment; you don't get rep for comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could turn add into a function,

http://jsfiddle.net/seSMx/3/

```
function add() {
   return 1 + (three || 0);
}

var three = 3;
document.getElementById('thediv').innerHTML = add();
```

Although, this would be very hard to follow in my opinion. I would take it a step farther and make `three` an argument to `add`

```
function add(three) {
   return 1 + (three || 0);
}

document.getElementById('thediv').innerHTML = add(3);
```

Answer (score 6):

is this what are you going for?

```js
var add = "1 + three";
var three = 3;
document.getElementById('thediv').innerHTML = eval(add);
```

Comment: `'eval'.replace(/a/,'i');` - Just sayin'. But it *does* work here.

Comment: sure it's eval - wouldn't use it at all - but the original question seemed to need it - but must say that the function version looks much better